# Custom decorator to pass dynamic title before executing function - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, decorator

I have a custom decorator function which is being called before any item to delete.

`confirmable.decorator.ts`

```
// we are now also importing SweetAlertOptions in our decorator
import Swal, {SweetAlertOptions} from 'sweetalert2';

// Confirmable is now a factory function, with an optional parameter object
export function Confirmable(options?: SweetAlertOptions) {

  // our factory function will return our actual decorator function, but now we have
  // an actual options object to configure our alert box :)
  return (target: Object, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => {
    // the usual, caching the original implementation
    const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
    // default values for our config, we’ll overwrite this with our options parameter
    const config: SweetAlertOptions = {
      title: 'Are you sure?',
      html: 'Do you want to perform this action?',
      showDenyButton: true,
      confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
      denyButtonText: 'No',
      icon: 'question'
    };

    // overwrite any keys passed in to our decorator in the config object
    if (options){
      Object.keys(options).forEach( x => config[x] = options[x]);
    }
    
    // from here it’s the same as before. We write the new implementation
    descriptor.value = async function (...args) {
      // ask for confirmation
      const res = await Swal.fire(config);
      
      if (res.isConfirmed){
         // run original implementation if user confirms
        const result = originalMethod.apply(this, args);
        return result;
      }
    };
    return descriptor;

  };

}
```

My code to implement.

```
  @Confirmable({title: 'Are you sure to delete this case study?' })
  deleteCaseStudy(caseId): void {
   this._caseStudy.deleteCaseStudy(caseId);
  }
```

[image]

What I want ?

I want to pass that `caseId` from parameter of function from `deleteCaseStudy(caseId)` to  `@Confirmable({title: caseId })` like this.

Right now all the text are static like shown in screenshot.

[credit link](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/building-custom-typescript-decorators-for-angular-4595816e7b87)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you see in your decorator you has

```
....
descriptor.value = async function (...args) {
  //here you has the "args" of your function:

  console.log(args)  //e.g.

  //we can use some with the args, e.g.
  config.title=args[0]

  // ask for confirmation
  const res = await Swal.fire(config);
  if (res.isConfirmed){
     // run original implementation if user confirms
    const result = originalMethod.apply(this, args);
    return result;
  }
};
return descriptor;
```

So, you can pass to your function delete an object with id and title

```
@Confirmable()
delete(args:{id:number,title?:string})
{
   const {id,title}=args
   //make something with "id"
}
```

use in your .html some like

```
<tr *ngFor=let row of elements>
   <td (click)="delete({id:row.id,title:'Delete '+row.id}">
</tr>
```

And in your decorator

```
...
 descriptor.value = async function (...args) {

 //here you has the "args" of your function:
 const {title,rest}=args[0]
 if (title)
  config.title=title
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kqagh3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fconfirmation.decorator.ts)

or pass as second argument

```
<tr *ngFor=let row of elements>
   <td (click)="delete(id,'Delete '+row.id}">
</tr>

@Confirmable()
delete(id:number,title:any=null)
```

And in decorator

```
 if (args[1])
  config.title=args[1]
```